# In Azure SQL Server How do I Query a table in db_1 from db_2 and insert records in table in db_2

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-sql-server

I need to identify fields in tbl_1 (2+ x 10^6 rows) in db_1 that do not match what is supposed to be the same field in tbl_2 in db_2 and insert an error log record in a tbl_3 in db_1 when a mismatch is found.
Azure SQL Server does not allow me to "FROM" tbl_2 in db_2. It barfs on "db_2.dbo.tbl_2". Is this not possible in Azure SQL Server?

Error message:
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Reference to database and/or server name in 'dbCaseMgmtSystemData.dbo.CM_CASE_DOCKET' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: This should not be a mind-reading exercise. If you encounter an error, post the complete error message. All of it - including severity, number, etc. That suggestion applies to any question you may ask in any technical forum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross database queries.How to proper use cross database features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122625/cross-database-queries-how-to-proper-use-cross-database-features)

Comment: error message added (my bad!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-Database Queries is supported in Azure SQL. This [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/) explains how to do that. You can query `tbl_2` in `db_2` and insert into  tables in `db_1`. You need to define a stored procedure to implement your processing logic.

Comment: Thanks. I am one step closer to getting this working!